# How can I safely sign a metal print?

Tags: fine-art

I'm looking at producing some larger fine art pieces printed on metal (there are a few pro vendors which do this).  If I wanted to sign these pieces (on the front, in the corner), does anyone know of a type of pen that could be used which won't damage the art and will hold up over time?

Comment: So, btw, is there a reason that this question applies only to metal prints?  Wouldn't acidic pens that would damage a metal print over time also damage a normal photograph?

Comment: I find even fine point sharpie too broad and does not distribute evenly therefore looking for an alternative

Answer (score 10):

We debated this on digital grin once, and came to two conclusions:

1. Pilot Acid Free Paint Pen
2. Bic Markit

https://dgrin.com/discussion/171308/signing-metal-prints

Comment: +1 The gist of the discussion on dgrin is that it should be acid free and dry quickly, so anything that meets that should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Answer received from a customer service supervisor at Bay Photo, one of the leading vendors which does metal prints:

> ...we have tested many types of
>   markers and pens on our metal prints.
>   We have found that the [Bic Mark-it](http://www.bicmarkit.com/products/products.aspx)
>   works the best. It is permanent and
>   does not rub off.

Answer (score 1):

A **standard** 'Sharpie' permanent marker contains acid, but..

Sharpie lists on [their website](http://www.sharpie.com/enUS/Products/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=SharpieWater-BasedPaintMarkerFine(Sharpie%20Catalog)) a few ones that are 'acid free' and for 'archival quality', those should be fine.